# Gooddata - Custom Attribute Buckets - Custom Filters

Tags: gooddata

How do I go about bucketing an attribute for use in a filter?

For example, let's say I have an attribute called 'site' with 4 different values. The values are: 
www.purple1.com --- www.purpleXX.com --- www.blue1.com --- www.blueXX.com

I wish I had the ability to create a new attribute called 'Product_Site' that would have two values, 'Purple' and 'Blue' based on the values in the 'site' attribute.

This way I could create a dashboard that had a chart that contained all sites, but I could use the 'Product_Site' filter to only shows sites regarding certain products.

The calculated attribute feature, I don't believe would allow me to do this, because you can only bucket by numerical values (it's based off of a metric). 
And the other method of creating two separate metrics and having those sites filtered within the metric wouldn't work, because I can't create a dashboard filter for metrics.

Please help me determine a way to group attribute values so that they can be filtered upon. Think of it like this, if I am looking at this dashboard and I support product Purple, I want a way to filter the dashboard so that I only see product purple. I don't want to have to manually filter for the million sites that may roll into product purple.

I imagine this comes up frequently when people want to filter on Europe instead of having to filter for all european countries.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for such feature in GoodData UI. This is usually solved within LDM and ETL - I mean you have to enrich LDM about attribute which reflects this relation - see example of csv file:

```
site,Product_Site
www.purple1.com,Purple
www.purpleXX.com,Purple
www.blue1.com,Blue
www.blueXX.com,Blue
```

Then you can use the attribute Product_Site as filter within dashboard.